# Different drivers for different Nvidia GPUs in the same system

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, gpgpu

I have the following two video cards installed in my Arch Linux system:

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [Quadro FX 1700] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 [Tesla C2050 / C2070] (rev a3)
```

I am interested in using the Quadro FX 1700 for the display with the open
source [Nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) driver.  I want to use
the Tesla C2070 card for CUDA development using the [Nvidia
driver](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Currently, I am using the `nvidia` and `nvidia-utils` packages for both the
display and CUDA.  However, I get better display stability when I am using
Nouveau.  If I install the package `xf86-video-nouveau` and comment out the
blacklist in `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf`, then Nouveau appears to take
over both cards.  In this state `nvidia-smi` returns the following:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidiactl (No such file or directory).
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Is it possible to "attach" Nouveau only to the Quadro and let the Nvidia driver
pick up the Tesla?